# subsetting data frames and creating nested lists

Tags: r, list

I have ***time series*** for each ***product***:

```
ts <- list()
ts[["p1"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p2"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p3"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p4"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p5"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
```

and a relationship between ***product*** and ***category*** in a data frame

```
category <- c("cA","cA","cB","cB","cB")
product <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5")
df_product_category <- data.frame(product,category)
```

I first want a ***list*** for each ***category***:

```
list_category <- list(unique(df_product_category$category))
#this doesn´t work
```

Then I want to create another ***list*** per ***category*** containing all the ***products*** within the category

```
list_category <- c("cA","cB")
```

once I have this list I need a nested list for each category containing each of the ***products*** within that ***category***

```
list_product_category <- list()
list_product_category$'cA' <- c("p1","p2")
list_product_category$'cB' <- c("p2","p3","p4")
```

then I wish to create another list ***nesting***: ***category-product-tslike*** this:

```
ts_list_product_category <- list()
ts_list_product_category[[cA]]$p1 <- ts[["p1"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cA]]$p2 <- ts[["p2"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p3 <- ts[["p3"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p4 <- ts[["p4"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p5 <- ts[["p5"]]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please check your previous question.  It is already answered i.e. `list_product_category <- with(df_product_category,    
          split(as.character(product), category));

out <-  lapply(list_product_category, function(x) ts[x])`

Comment: In `data.frame` call, be sure to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` which is now the default setting of [R 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)!